# "a saving of " VS "savings of"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. And the investments and efforts that we will be making in 2016 and 2017 will mean **savings** of  15-16 million.
> 2. And the investments and efforts that we will be making in 2016 and 2017 will mean **a saving** of  15-16 million.

I have seen for the most time savings, but I am wondering here "a saving of" could be better since it is one saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[savings](https://investinganswers.com/financial-dictionary/personal-finance/savings-6081) is an economics term. Typically, in economics, you have investment and savings. That is true in business also.

> "In economics, **savings is the amount that is left after spending**. In
>   banking, savings refers to savings accounts, which are short-term,
>   interest-bearing deposits with a bank or other financial institution."

Often, when discussing investments, one investment (money spent) will be compared to another in terms of how much less you might spend on one rather than another. The savings (money not spent) in investment A can represent some amount when compared to investment B. The term in this context is always in the plural. One always looks to spend less and make more.

Also, in terms of personal finances, people refer to the savings with an s. **This term is not about the possibility of saying "saving"; it is about the term used in businesses such as banking,finance and investment and in personal finances.**

Answer (score 2):

**[a savings](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20savings%20of%20over%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)** refers to an amount you did not have to spend because the total price of something was less in comparison to some other price, either the original price before a discount or rebate was applied, or a price from another vendor, say.

> There was a 15% discount on first-time purchases. On that $100 item it represented **a savings** of $15.
>
> The wholesale price kicks in with quantities over a dozen. The difference can represent a significant savings for the consumer.

Comment: You can also have savings for things other than money. For example "According to a 2008 federal Department of Energy study, U.S. electricity use decreased by 0.5% for each day of extended daylight saving time, **resulting in a savings of 0.03% for the year as a whole**, KING-TV, Seattle, reported." ([*](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2015/10/28/daylight-saving-time-5-things-know/74737608/))

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, an amount [of electricity or whatever] that was not used and associated with a cost.

Answer (score 0):

If the actions that led to money being saved are plural, then savings were made. One such action makes a saving.